# Is there a formula for a reversed chain rule?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, chain-rule

Imagine I have a vector field $f^a(x,y)$ that depends on vector positions $x^i$ and $y^i$ with $i=1,\dots,N$. The index $a=1,\dots,M$. Now, let's say There's another function $G: R^M\rightarrow R$ and I want to evaluate

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} G(f^a(x,y))
\end{equation}

This can be easily done with the chain rule. We get

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} G(f^a(x,y))= \frac{\partial f^a(x,y)}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}G(u) 
\end{equation}

My question is: Is there a way to to the opposite calculation to get

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}G(u) =\big[\frac{\partial f^a(x,y)}{\partial x^i}\big]^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} G(f^a(x,y))
\end{equation}

and when is this well defined?

Comment: Perhaps writing the chain rule in matrix notation would make the situation clearer to you. Also, don’t forget that your partial derivatives of $G$ have to be evaluated at $f(x,y)$.

Comment: The “inverse” can also be found by using “inverse” matrices as @TedShifrin said, but this may be a different notion of “inverse”.

Comment: Au contraire. Do dimensions even match?